# Need help understanding some typescript

Tags: typescript

I am looking at some typescript code for the first time and I'm clear on what it does until the last line. I believe that is a Nullish coalescing operator but I don't understand why the regex result is written **matches?.[1]** when **matches[1]** appears to work. Can anyone help with this?

```
const titleRegex = /<title(?:.*?)>(.*?)<\/title>/
const extractTitle = (website: string): string => {
  const matches = titleRegex.exec(website)
  return matches?.[1] ?? ''
}
```

Comment: `matches` can be `null` if the regex doesn't match anything

Answer (score 0):

It is a protective approach. It would look similar to this without the grammar

```
if(matches != null && matches[1] != null) {
  return matches[1];
} else {
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) but an [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

It's quite simple, it works like other optional chaining (meanings this code won't throw errors like "toto property doesn't exist on undefined" but will return `undefined` instead.

```js
const data = {};
console.log(data?.toto);
```

the optional chaining can also be used to **array elements** or **functions**, like:

```js
const toto = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(toto[1]);    // will print 2
console.log(toto?.[1]);  // will print 2
// Now let's imagine toto is undefined for whatever reasons
console.log(toto[42]);   // will throw "can't read property '42' of undefined"
console.log(toto?.[42]); // will print "undefined"

console.log("toto");     // will print "toto"
console.log?.("toto");   // will print "toto"
console.toto("toto");    // will throw an error "console.toto is not a function
console.toto?.("toto");  // will return "undefined"
```

And so far the [regex.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value) routine will return:

> An `Array` whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or **`null`** if no matches are found.

Since it can be null, you'll need to handle the case where your data is either an array or null.

Comment: Thanks for all answers - I now understand the optional chaining but isn't the double question mark in that final line a Nullish coalescing operator? If not, what does that do?